# How to prove this is a partial order?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, order-theory

A relation is defined by:
$x\leq y$ if and only if there exists $\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y= x+5k$.
Prove that $\leq$ is a partial order.

I have no idea how to do this question. I've tried my best to try and solve but to no avail. If anybody can help me out with this question, it would really be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Whenever you are stuck on a math problem, always write out the definitions.  That is pretty much always the first step of the problem and usually the last step as well.  Sometimes if you write the definitions of the givens and the goals you have written the first and last third of the proof.  Also, this site discourages questions where no work is shown.  You'll likely get downvotes instead of answers if you don't add something of your own to the question.  Oh, and math formatting tips are [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti Thank you ! Will see what I can do with it.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor Sure. I shall follow the tips you've given. Yes, I know math.stackechange doesn't encourage questions without effort in it. But I literally don't know how to proceed with the question, hence posted here. Hope you understand.. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relation "$\leq$" is a partial order if it is

---

1. Reflexive: $x\leq x$.

This is clear since $x=x+5\cdot 0$, assuming your set of natural numbers includes $0$.

---

2. Antisymmetric: $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$ implies $x=y$.

If $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$ then by definition there exist $k_1,k_2\in \mathbb{N}$
such that $x=y+5k_1$ and $y=x+5k_2.$ Solving these two equations you find that $k_1=-k_2.$ and thus $k_1=k_2=0$ since $k_1,k_2\in \mathbb{N}$. Hence $x=y$.

---

3. Transitive: $x\leq y$ and $y\leq z $ implies $x\leq z$.

Since $x\leq y$ and $y\leq z$, there exist $m_1,m_2\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$x=y+5m_1$ and $y=z+5m_2.$ From these two equations you have $x=z+5(m_1+m_2)$ and since $m_1+m_2\in \mathbb{N}$, $x\leq z$.

Comment: @math101 if you add the two equations(or solve using substitution)  you can get $k_1=-k_2$. But since $k_1$  and $k_2$ are both non negative integers(belong to $\mathbb{N}$, that is only possible if both are $0$. For example if $k_1=8$ then $k_2$ has to be $-8$ but that is not possible since $k_2$ is in the natural numbers. This means they have to be both $0$ for $k_1=-k_2$ to work.

Comment: Thank you  so much